# jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb or one of its dependencies installed once switched code to windows from ubuntu

Tags: jekyll, gitlab-ci

On Ubuntu v15 my Jekyll Blog with jekyll [lunr-js-search](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search) builds well as well as it gets build in gitlab-ci.

Now, I moved my project to Windows system with same versions of node, bower etc. I get following error on windows as well as gitlab-ci (*This error repeated on gitlab-ci when I've made only a single line change in post*). **HOW TO FIX ?**

***ERROR***

> > Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have /builds/sachingpta/home/_plugins/lunrjs/jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- v8' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got built on gitlab, it could be due to gitlab update with dashboard message: *We're currently deploying 8.17.0 RC2, so you may encounter intermittent errors*. Somebody mentioned that required dependency **therubyracer** does not compiles  on windows so this question is closed. I've to compile project on ubuntu only :(